# can i open an installed app with in my linear layout on a button click - Android Project

Tags: android

Can i open a third party installed app with in my linear layout 
 or in a frame layout, on a button click. What i mean, i want two app
 simultaneously. One is on top frame other is on bottom frame.

#### mainactivity.xml

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mulititask.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="some text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnbrowser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnpdbreader"
            android:text="open browser" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnpdbreader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnbrowser"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnbrowser"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="open pdb reader" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#991535" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnhide"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="hide this frame"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Open browser or pdb file viewer within this frame on default button click" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

#### mainactivity

```
package com.mulititask;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnbrowser, btncalc, btnhideframe;
    TableLayout tlayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btnhideframe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnhide); 
    btnbrowser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbrowser);
    btncalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpdbreader);
    tlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlayout); 

    tlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnhideframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
        }

    });



    btnbrowser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {
               i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.browser.ucweb");//"com.browser.ucweb" is not correct and thats not a problem. So leave it
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }

        }
    });

    btncalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Intent i;
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            try {
               i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.calculator.default");//"com.calculator.default" is not correct and thats not a problem. So leave it
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            }


        }
    });

    }
}
```

In this project i can open the app outside of my app, but cannot open within my table layout. is there any codding to open apps in such a way?

Comment: No this is not possible, (maybe due to security Android reasons)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. in a logical sense i have same feeling as you tell. But samsung introduced multi app supporting mobiles. i used a app witch support multi app opener app, some years ago. but i am not sure it was with android, may be with jar supporting mobile.

Comment: When this app you used is only available on Samsung devices it could be possible that Samsung implemented the app in C++. It the same for ASUS they prove a multi-app-opener app which is implemented in C++ and not in Java to provide this functionality. So it not a native Java App. They ship the app with their devices and these apps may have system priviliges that native jana apps  typically don't have

Comment: Thanks for your info. Your comment saves my time. i am going to find a n another way. May be with kill app or some other method.